# Is “help out” an inappropriate phrase?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

I have seen statements like:

> She helped out her grandmother.

OR

> The boy was helping out in the laundry.

But, does it make any sense to have the “out” there? Is it even incorrect, in spite of the prevalent usage?

Comment: "helping out" is an idiom. Idioms don't need to make grammatical sense.

Comment: Hi LWTBP - When in doubt about words usage or meaning pls refer also to a good dictionary. We will be pleased to help you if your doubts persist. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[To help out](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/help+out) is a phrasal verb meaning:

> 1. to assist or aid (someone), esp by sharing the burden
> 2. to share the burden or cost of something with (another person)

- help out - *be of help, as in a particular situation of need*; "Can you help out tonight with the dinner guests

Source: Collins English Dictionary